# SmartDL for ftp

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

I need a python code which can download files from a ftp server. I need a built in multi-part download managing package which can help me to retrieve files faster. I tried [SmartDL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pySmartDL/) but the problem is I don't know how to retrieve files in a ftp server. Also I used the add_basic_authentication to ensure that, I am passing the right credentials. Please help me with a solution.

I have no problem using any other solution/package which uses Multipart download.

P.S:- I need to save the Downloaded files on to an Object storage on Cloud. The size of each file may be 300MB and I need to download 20TB of data.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), it's a simple FTP library which will permit you to download files from a FTP server.

Comment: I dont think that supports Multipart download.